# The play command of my Discord bot on Wavelink doesn't work, how to fix it?

Tags: python, discord, bots

Here is the play command for my bot:

```
@client.tree.command(name="play", description="Play some music")
@app_commands.describe(musicname="The name of the music you want to play")
async def play(interaction:Interaction, musicname:str):
    '''Play music'''
    search = await wavelink.YouTubeTrack.search(query=musicname, return_first=True)
    if not getattr(interaction.user.voice, "channel", None):
        return await interaction.response.send_message("You are not in a voice channel", ephemeral=True)
    elif not interaction.guild.voice_client:
        voiceclient: wavelink.Player = await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player, self_deaf=True)
    else:
        voiceclient: wavelink.Player = interaction.guild.voice_client

    if not voiceclient.is_playing():
        await voiceclient.play(search)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Now playing `{search.title}`")
    else:
        await voiceclient.queue.put_wait(search)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Added `{search.title}` to the queue")
```

Also for on_wavelink_track_end:

```
@client.event
async def on_wavelink_track_end(player:Player, track:YouTubeTrack, reason:str):
    '''When track ends'''
    voiceclient: Player = player.guild.voice_client

    if voiceclient.loop:
        return await voiceclient.play(track)
    elif not voiceclient.queue.is_empty:
        next_song = voiceclient.queue.get()
        await voiceclient.play(next_song)
        await player.interaction.response.send_message(f"Now playing `{next_song.title}`")
    else:
        print("finished playing")
```

As soon as I type on Discord /play something, the bot writes into console "finished playing", that means the bot doesn't even play the song and finishes playing it as soon as execute the command.
Please help me with it!

Expected: play music
Reality: write into the chat "Playing something" and into the console "finished playing"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it very easily:
I just replaced the node lavalinkinc.ml to lavalink.botsuniversity.ml and it began to work.